# MSBuild looks for Main when building a project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I am working on a large project that consists of multiple executables. I'd like to automate deployment process by building all of them at once. That is why I resorted to `msbuild` command line utility.

When I build one of my projects in Visual Studio it build normally. When I try to do the same using msbuild cmd, it fails with an error

```
CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [pathToLibrary.csproj]
```

This is cmd code:

```
msbuild MainProject.csproj -property:Configuration=Release -property:Platform="AnyCPU" -property:OutputType="WinExe" -target:"Rebuild"
```

pathToLibrary.csproj indeed is a library so I don't know why `msbuild` is trying to find a main method. There is none. It is a library.

What am I missing here?

Comment: "There is none. It is a library." - Then the output type shouldn't be set to WinExe. That's the problem, I strongly suspect. Why are you specifying that on your command line at all?

Comment: MainProject.csproj contains a reference to pathToLibrary.csproj library. Error is not triggered for MainProject, but for pathToLibrary.csproj. Excuse me for bad naming convention :)

Comment: That is, I am building MainProject, which happens to reference a library. The Main method missing error is for library, not for MainProject.

Comment: It look like that WinExe OutputType is also being applied to library.csproj. Not only for MainProject.csproj

Comment: Why specify it at all on the command line? Surely the project should know what type of output to produce, and that's what it will do in VS. Have you *tried* not specifying it on the command line?

Comment: Not specifying fixes it. I prefer writing a batch file and run it every time I need to build all of my projects that work together as a unit and specify any configurations in one place. Perhaps I am being too picky. If there is no way to instruct msbuild to only overwrite OutputType for main .csproj, editing every file separately will have to  do.

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't want the project file to know the correct type of output. If you have multiple configurations, you can express that in MSBuild *as* configurations, and vary the output type based on that. I think that's much better than specifying the output type as an MSBuild property on the command line.

Comment: Thanks. I've went with the solution very similar to what you and Jon Skeet suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> pathToLibrary.csproj indeed is a library so I don't know why msbuild
>   is trying to find a main method. There is none. It is a library.

When your main project references projects by `Add Reference`-->`Projects`, it will always build not only the main projects but also the referenced projects at the same time. So when you build that project by MSBuild command lines, `-property:OutputType=winexe` will also apply to these referenced projects. When you build the project in VS IDE and MSBuild, you will see these info in output log.

[image]

[image]

> If there is no way to instruct msbuild to only overwrite OutputType
>   for main .csproj, editing every file separately will have to do

If you just want to find a way to specify `-property:OutputType=winexe` to the main project not the referenced projects by MSBuild command line, I think there is no such function.

Or you could try my **suggestions**:

**1)** please remove `-property:OutputType=winexe` in MSBuild command line and when you create the related project, you have already specified the output type of the project, so you don't need to specify it in MSBuild which is not the job of the MSBuild.

**Note** that you can modify the property in `xxx.csproj` directly like `<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>`.

**2)** if you still want this feature when you build the project with MSBuild command line, I suggest you could create a script called [Directory.Build.targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets) which can overwrite the `OutputType` property and then build the project separately with MSBuild.

**~a)** please create a file called `Directory.Build.targets` in every project folder which the `xxxx.csproj` file exists.

**~b)** write the related property about the project in it:(use **Exe** in a console project ,use **WinExe** in a windows project and use **Library** in a class library project.)

```
 <Project>
    <Target Name="inputproperty" BeforeTargets="AssignProjectConfiguration">
    <PropertyGroup>
     <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    </PropertyGroup>
    </Target>
    </Project>
```

write like this in your **MainProject** project and then create another `Directory.Build.targets` in your **pathToLibrary** project to use `<OutputType>Library</OutputType>` so that it will meet your expectations.